# How can I exclude a page from browser's history?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, browser-history

I want to exclude page-1 from the browser history, so that when I navigate away from it, (let's say to page-2) and then press the back button, it won't show page-1.

Or else, if going from 1 -> 2 disables the back button on 2.

Is there any way this can be accomplished? (Not using javascript)

I've a form on page-1, on successful submission of which page 2 is shown.
However, I don't want page-1 to be shown when I click on back button on page-2.
Either it should be disabled or it should revert form submission (deleting all the session variables) and then show page 1.

How can this be done?

I'm using Spring MVC and JSP views in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a session parameter when displaying the page to enforce the user to visit page1 before they visit page2.

```
@RequestMapping("/page1.html")
public String page1(HttpSession session){
    session.setAttribute("seen_page_1", "true");
    return "page1";
}

@RequestMapping("/page2.html")
public String page2(HttpSession session){
    if(!"true".equals(session.getAttribute("seen_page_1").toString())){
        return "redirect:/page1.html";
    }
    return "page2";
}
```

If you want to display page2 to users who have already visited page1 (even when they return to the page), you could use a cookie value instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long you want this behavior to last you can store the form status from page 1 in a session var or cookie. Session vars will last as long as the user has their browser open. You can set the expiration for a cookie to last a few minutes or to never expire.

You can set up a [filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) between requests for page 1 and page 2. In the filter check for either the session var or cookie. If the value is for a submitted form then redirect to page 2. If the value is not set or set to something else (depending on your implementation) then redirect to page 1.